# How to get Information from JSON object using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json, jsonp

My Json objects are inside a external file named abc.json in my js file I am calling it. I have a html markup like this

```
<li class="" data-flight-name="kingfisher" data-flight-id="E6-184"></li>
<li class="" data-flight-name="indigo" data-flight-id="E6-185"></li>
```

My requirement is when ever i click on that LI pass this data-flight-name and data-flight-id while fetching the information through JSON but while fetching I am not getting proper data.

My Json File structure is

```
{
  "flightInfo" :{
    "indigo": [
          {"E-184" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 1753, "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"}},
          {"E-185" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 1753, "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"}},
          {"E-186" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "2h:30m", "baseFare": 8000, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}},
          {"E-187" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "6h:30m", "baseFare": 6000, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}},
          {"E-189" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "5h:0m", "baseFare": 9907, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}}
      ],

    "kingfisher": [
          {"E-184" : {"flightName": "KF RED", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 2819, "travelTime": "10:13 - 11:13"}},
          {"E-184" : {"flightName": "KF RED", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 2819, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}},
          {"E-184" : {"flightName": "KF RED", "duration": "2h:30m", "baseFare": 18000, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}},
          {"E-184" : {"flightName": "KF RED", "duration": "6h:30m", "baseFare": 16000, "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"}}
      ]
  }
}
```

Used jquery for fetching information is

```
$("#list li").delegate("", "click", function(e){
        var dataflightname = $(this).attr('data-flight-name'),
            dataflightid = $(this).attr('data-flight-id');
//            console.log(dataflightname);
//            console.log(dataflightid);
        if($(this).siblings().hasClass('selected')){
          $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
          $(this).addClass('selected');
          // Featcing Flights Information
          $.getJSON("javascript/abc.json",function(data){

            $(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][0]).each(function(key, items) {
              $(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][key]).each(function(key, items) {
              //Reading name tag value
              //here i am not getting proper value
              console.log(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][0][items]);
              });
            });
          });
        }
      });
```

Please help to understand why I am not able to get the all values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the syntax for `.delegate()` a bit mixed up, it goes: `$(<root element>).delegate(<selector>, <event>, <callback>)`. When you try to access your JSON object you append a `[0]` onto the end which is unnecessary (`data.flightInfo[dataflightname][0]` should be `data.flightInfo[dataflightname]`):

```
$("#list").delegate("li", "click", function(e){
    var $this          = $(this),
        dataflightname = $this.attr('data-flight-name'),
        dataflightid   = $this.attr('data-flight-id');

    if($this.siblings().hasClass('selected')){
      $this.siblings().removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // Featcing Flights Information
      $.getJSON("javascript/abc.json",function(data){
        for (var i = 0, len = data.flightInfo[dataflightname].length; i < len; i++) {
            console.log(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][i]);
            //output will be (for the first index): {"E-184" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 1753, "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"}}
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HscZX/

Notice I cached the `$(this)` selector in the `$this` variable since it was being used so many times which should improve performance. Also I changed out the `$.each()` loop for a `for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {}` beacuse the later performs **much** faster. Check-out this jsperf to see the difference in performance: http://jsperf.com/for-in-tests/4

Comment: Very nicely structured example!

Comment: On jsfiddle I am not able to see any output. Yes code is there but on click nothing happened.

Comment: @saorabh I am outputting data using `console.log` so you need to loop at your developer console to see the output. Also, make sure to click on `Indigo`, your code requires that one of the `<li>`s have the `selected` class so I added that to the `Kingfisher` `<li>` tag.

Comment: Thank you @Jasper Really I learn a lot thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit your javascript as below:

```
$("#list li").delegate("", "click", function(e){
    var dataflightname = $(this).attr('data-flight-name'),
    dataflightid = $(this).attr('data-flight-id');
    if($(this).siblings().hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        // Featcing Flights Information
        $.getJSON("/cygnet-ng/test.json",function(data){
            $(data.flightInfo[dataflightname]).each(function(key, items) {
                $(items).each(function(key1, items1) {
                //Reading name tag value 
                //here i am not getting proper value 
                    for(n in items1){
                           console.log(items1[n].flightName);
                           console.log(items1[n].duration);
                           console.log(items1[n].baseFare);
                           console.log(items1[n].travelTime);
                    }    
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This will iterate over the json data.

Comment: This help is really nice. Thanks for helping. Can I get the exact value relatively clicked li. Suppose If i click on this <li class="" data-flight-name="indigo" data-flight-id="E6-185"></li> I want only information having flight name indigo and id having E6-185. If you can help me please.. Thanking you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

first:change your data structure like this:

```
{
    "flightInfo": {
        "indigo": {
            "E-184": {
                "flightName": "Indigo",
                "duration": "1h:0m",
                "baseFare": 1753,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"
            },
            "E-185": {
                "flightName": "Indigo",
                "duration": "1h:0m",
                "baseFare": 1753,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"
            },
            "E-186": {
                "flightName": "Indigo",
                "duration": "2h:30m",
                "baseFare": 8000,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            },
            "E-187": {
                "flightName": "Indigo",
                "duration": "6h:30m",
                "baseFare": 6000,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            },
            "E-189": {
                "flightName": "Indigo",
                "duration": "5h:0m",
                "baseFare": 9907,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            }
        },

        "kingfisher": {
            "E-184": {
                "flightName": "KF RE}D",
                "duration": "1h:0m",
                "baseFare": 2819,
                "travelTime": "10:13 - 11:13"
            },
            "E-184": {
                "flightName": "KF RED",
                "duration": "1h:0m",
                "baseFare": 2819,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            },
            "E-184": {
                "flightName": "KF RED",
                "duration": "2h:30m",
                "baseFare": 18000,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            },
            "E-184": {
                "flightName": "KF RED",
                "duration": "6h:30m",
                "baseFare": 16000,
                "travelTime": "11:13 - 16:13"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then,what you want is:

`data.flightInfo[dataflightname][dataflightid]`;

```
$("#list li").click(function (e) {
    var dataflightname = $(this).attr('data-flight-name'),
        dataflightid = $(this).attr('data-flight-id');
    if ($(this).siblings().hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        // Featcing Flights Information
        $.getJSON("javascript/abc.json", function (data) {
            console.log(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][dataflightid]);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work because the keys for kingfisher are all the same ... so the bottom most will win and cover all the others.

Comment: After changing the json structure and when i am trying to fetch the console.log(data.flightInfo[dataflightname][dataflightid]); this I am getting undefined..

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze the following code parts

```
data.flightInfo[dataflightname][0]
```

With this line you will get `{"E-184" : {"flightName": "Indigo", "duration": "1h:0m", "baseFare": 1753, "travelTime": "11:13 - 12:13"}}` for "indigo" which is only the first entry for this dataflightname.

Next you are trying to loop all the keys for this entry. There is only one: `"E-184"`

So the following code line

```
data.flightInfo[dataflightname][key]
```

will be `data.flightInfo["indigo"]["E-184"]` which is undefined.

EDIT: It will help if you describe WHAT exactly you want to achieve

EDIT2: I think you have a typo somewhere ... E6-184 from the data-flight-id attribute doesn't match any enty in your JSON